# Interactive menu skips expected inputs

Tags: python

I'm attempting to program an interactive menu system. The output should look like this:

```
Welcome to Store
1. Add Item to Cart
2. Checkout your cart
3. Quit

Enter Your Option = 1
1 Burger
2 Fries
3 Coke
4 Shake

Choose the Product number want to buy (1 at a time) = 2
How Much Quantity (In Number) You want = 900

Welcome to Store
1. Add Item to Cart
2. Checkout
3. Quit

Enter Your Option = 2

Your Total Bill Amount Including 5% GST = 1890.0 $
Thank You For Shopping!!!
```

However, the output of what I have so far is skipping over the part where it asks for further input after selecting option 2. Current output:

```
Welcome to the store
----------------------
1.Add item to your cart
2.Checkout your cart
3.Quit
Select Choice = 1
Choose the item you want to purchase (1 at a time)=  
How Much you want to eat = 

Welcome to the store
----------------------
1.Add item to your cart
2.Checkout your cart
3.Quit
Select Choice =
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
GST = str(1.05)
OrderList = ["Burger", "Fries", "Coke"]
OrderCost = [5, 10, 15]

try:
    dataFile = open("Evil.txt", "r")
    data = dataFile.read().splitlines()
    dataFile.close()
except:
    print("Cannot open file!")
OrderList = []
OrderCost = []
try:
    for line in data:
        splitLine = line.split()
        OrderList.append(splitLine[0])
        OrderCost.append(int(splitLine[0]))
except ValueError:
    print("Value error in file!")
print(OrderList)
print(OrderCost)

totalItems = len(OrderList)

quantity = []

for item in range(totalItems):
    quantity.append(0)
   
while True:
    while True:
        print("\nWelcome to the store")
        print("----------------------")
        print("1.Add item to your cart")
        print("2.Checkout your cart")
        print("3.Quit")
        choice = int(input("Select Choice = "))
        if choice == 1:
            print("Choose the item you want to purchase (1 at a time)=  ")
            print("How Much you want to eat = ")
            
        elif choice == 2:
            print("Your Total Bill Amount Including 5% GST = " + GST)
            print("Thanks for shopping with us")
            exit()
        elif choice == 3:
            print("Program exited")
```

Why is it not behaving as intended?

Comment: For `choice == 1` shouldn't you ask the user to input the values?

Comment: Please don't post images of code/output. Copy and paste here as text (and format it as code).

Answer (score 2):

The reason it is skipping over where things need to be entered is because you are not giving the program a chance to accept input at all. You are just using `print()`. To accept input and store the response, use `input()`, like so:

```py
item = input("Choose the item you want to purchase (1 at a time)=  ")
quantity = input("How Much you want to eat = ")
```

Then, you can use `item` and `quantity` to determine what to do next, for example:

```py
if item == "1":
    OrderList.append(["Burger"] * quantity)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing those lines without using the input function, that is why it is "skipping" them. You miss part of the program.

Comment: Why does it skip the first 3 prints but not the next two?

Comment: I don't get the comment, I am saying that the user is printing "Choose the item..." etc. instead of asking the user, therefore it reasonably skips over. Also I do not get what Evil.txt is supposed to do.

Comment: I misunderstood the question. I thought he was asking why `1.Add item to your cart` isn't shown before the `Select Choice =` prompt.

Comment: I did too, at first. This is a great example of why code/output shouldn't be presented as screenshots.